# Swipe conflict between a cell and horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll, cell

Currently I have a horizontal scroll which has several pages inside. Some of these pages have tables with cells that have swipe.

> The idea is to be able to swipe the cell and when finished this swipe, somehow activate the scroll swipe to move to the next page. Something like this:

[image]

**But when I try, it occurs in conflict and 2 scroll at the same time activated. That is while the cell is moving and showing the button, the scroll also begins to move to the other page.**

For the swipe cell I'm using `SWTableViewCell` because the native functionality like the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    }
}
```

Not even activated, they ignore the swipe of the cell completely and only swipe the scroll is activated.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your gif doesn't work. i think it would be better to design a different UI. you know swiping and continuing to swipe in mail app results in delete right?

Comment: sorry @Wain added gift again

Comment: Why don't you use a page view controller with a table view inside of it?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your horizontal scroll view, have you set the following:

```
scrollView.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

More information on this can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624218-cancelstouchesinview

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    if ([[otherGestureRecognizer.view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass: [UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *otherPan = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
            CGPoint translation = [otherPan translationInView:otherGestureRecognizer.view];
            return translation.x < 0;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```